# Ruby PDFLib on OSX: LoadError in require

Tags: ruby, macos, pdflib

I just downloaded and installed the Ruby for OSX version of PDFLib (from pdflib.com).
I am using the following setup:
    `ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]`
    `OSX Yosemite 10.10.4`
    `PDFLib 9.0.5`

The `require 'PDFLib'` statement in my Ruby file produces the following error message:
`/Users/[...]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': dlsym(0x7ff6e3ef4b90, Init_PDFLib): symbol not found - [...]/PDFLib.bundle (LoadError)`

So it seems that the Ruby interpreter cannot find the `Init_PDFLib` in the library. But from the output of `nm` I gather that this symbol seems to be present:
`$ nm -g ./PDFlib.bundle | grep -i init`
`0000000000001200 T _Init_PDFlib`
`[...]`

Has anyone any idea what goes wrong? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

The PDFlib file is called PDF**l**ib.bundle (small *l*), and my code did a require 'PDF**L**ib' (capitalized *L*).
It turns out that the require does load the bundle file regardless of the wrong capitalization, but then searches for the Init_PDF**L**ib symbol, which is not present.
So changing the require statement to `require 'PDFlib'` (small *l*) worked.